# Delete a desired entry on a post preg_replace

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do I get a query with a regular expression in the form of?

```
$data = "select * from table where id=5 AND ( round(data) = 2 ) AND ( round(data) = 5 ) AND FIND_IN_SET('159',data)";
$data = preg_replace("/AND ( round(data) = \d+ )/", "", $data);
$data = preg_replace("/AND FIND_IN_SET('\d+',data)/", "", $data);
```

Output:

```
select * from table where id=5
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the resulting query you want?

Comment: select * from table where id=5 - I want to do with regular

Comment: Why can't you just use an "if" statements and concatenation of queries?

Comment: my goal is to delete the same filters with different values. I can do this with regular

Comment: you need to delete the same filters with different values without living removed filter in the original query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version of your code:

```
$data = "select * from table where id=5 AND ( round(data) = 2 ) AND ( round(data) = 5 ) AND FIND_IN_SET('159',data)";
$data = preg_replace("/AND \( round\(data\) = \d+ \)/", "", $data);
$data = preg_replace("/AND FIND_IN_SET\('\d+',data\)/", "", $data);
```

It was not working as expected because you forgot to place `\` before `(` and `)`. From PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

PHP treats `(` and `)` as `blocks` for matches.